# Signlar client not executing connection.on method

Tags: signalr, service-worker, signalr.client

I have a Signaler client in worker service. developed Signaler server in .net core web API.
Here everything is working but when I am calling.

```
 await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("calldscclient", desUserList.FirstOrDefault().DscConnectionId);
```

From the server, it's not sending a message to the client

```
 connection.On<string>("calldscclient", (message) => {}
```

I am writing my client code here.

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
 using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
 using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic; 
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Net;
 using System.Net.Http;
 using System.Net.Sockets;
 using System.Threading;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using WorkerService1.Properties;

namespace WorkerService1
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public  HubConnection connection;
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        //while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new 
            StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\devma\source\repos\WorkerService1\WorkerService1\TextFile1.txt"))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("bigin");

            }

            var ip = GetLocalIPAddress();
            ip = "localhost";

            connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            //.WithUrl(new Uri("https://localhost:5001/dschub"))
            //.WithAutomaticReconnect(new RandomRetryPolicy())
            //.Build();

                .WithUrl("https://localhost:44339/dschub"
                ,
                options =>
                {
                    options.WebSocketConfiguration = conf =>
                    {
                        conf.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => 
                     { return true; };
                    };
                    options.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = factory => new HttpClientHandler
                    {
                        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => 
                     { return true; }
                    };
                    
                }
            )
               .Build();



            await connection.StartAsync();
            await connection.InvokeAsync("dscRegister", ip);



            connection.On<string>("calldscclient", (message) =>
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new  
             
            StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\devma\source\repos\WorkerService1\WorkerService1\TextFile1.txt"))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("Monica Rathbun");

                }
            });

        }

    }
    public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
    {
        var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                return ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!");
    }
  } 
 }
```

For calling

```
connection.On<string>("calldscclient", (message) => {}
```

I am using web API on the server.
My WebAPI code is here.

```
    [HttpGet("servedsc")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ServeDsc()
    {

        var remoteIpAddress = HttpContext.Request.Host.Host;
        var desUserList = await _dscService.GetDscUser(remoteIpAddress);
        await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("calldscclient", 
        desUserList.FirstOrDefault().DscConnectionId);
        //await 
        _hub.Clients.User(desUserList.FirstOrDefault().DscConnectionId).SendAsync("calldscclient");
        return Ok(desUserList);
    }
```

Here everything is working fine like Signaler Hub is executing property when the client making a connection.
But the problem is when the server is sending messages to the client it's not getting.

Answer (score 0):

You should generally register your `.On` method handlers before starting the connection. In your case, you're awaiting `InvokeAsync` which will invoke the server method and **wait** for the server method to finish. Then you are registering your `.On` method which will be too late at that point.

Comment: Now I did the same as u suggest Still not working

Comment: connection.On("calldscclient", () =>
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\devma\source\repos\WorkerService1\WorkerService1\TextFile1.txt"))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine("Monica Rathbun");

                    }
                });

                await connection.StartAsync();
                await connection.InvokeAsync("dscRegister", ip);

Comment: even i have removed
await connection.InvokeAsync("dscRegister", ip);
But still not working

Comment: Is DscConnectionId a string or a different type?

Comment: DscConnectionId  is a string type

Comment: i changed in API
await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("calldscclient");
No connectionid needed now 
Still not working

Comment: API executing successfully and giving proper response

Comment: You still need to pass a string to `calldscclient`. Silly question, are you sure the client is connected when you call the API?

Comment: I am 100% sure that the client is connected.

Comment: I told you everything is working but the callback is not

Comment: You know this is worker service and it's running when I am calling web API.